# How to get rid of this global variable when using the recursion?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

First of all, I don't want to use `sort`. This is just an illustration example. The main purpose of this question is that I want to:

> find all possible combinations of `m` numbers out of `n` numbers and
>    process them, then return the unique processed result (since the
>   processed results of all possible combinations will be compared).

### Question start at here

The following code get all possible combinations `M` numbers out of `N` numbers. Sum the `M` numbers and find the largest sum. In doing this I used a recursion function.

**However, it seems that I must define a global variable to store the temporary largest sum.** Is there any way to get rid of this global variable? For example, define the recursion function to return the largest sum... I don't want the global variable just become an argument `&max_sum` in the `find_sum`, since `find_sum` already have too many arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void find_sum(const std::vector<int>& ar, std::vector<int>&  combine,
        int index, int start);

int max_sum =0;

int main()  {
    int N = 10;
    int M = 3;
    std::vector<int> ar(N); 
    ar = {0,9,2,3,7,6,1,4,5,8};

    int index = 0, start =0;
    std::vector<int> combine(M);
    find_sum(ar, combine, index, start);
    std::cout << max_sum <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void find_sum(const std::vector<int>& ar, std::vector<int>&  combine, 
        int index, int start) {

    if(index == combine.size())  {
        int sum =0;
        for(int i=0; i<index; ++i)  {
            sum += combine[i];
        }
        if(max_sum < sum)   {
            max_sum = sum;
        }
        return ;
    }

    for(int i = start; 
            i < ar.size() && ar.size()-i > combine.size()-index; 
            ++i) {
        combine[index] = ar[i];
        find_sum(ar, combine, index+1, start+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I often do is I do define the recursive function as having the extra parameters, but I define a helper which is called by the user, and the helper calls the recursive function with initial values.

Answer (score 2):

An approach that scales well is to turn `find_sum` into a *function object*. The trick is to define a `struct` with an overloaded `()` operator that takes a certain set of parameters:

```
struct FindSum
{
    void operator()(const std::vector<int>& ar, std::vector<int>&  combine, 
        int index, int start){
        /*ToDo - write the function here, a very explicit way of
        /*engineering the recursion is to use this->operator()(...)*/
    }

    int max_sum; // I am now a member variable
};
```

Then instantiate `FindSum find_sum;`, set `find_sum.max_sum` if needed (perhaps even do that in a *constructor*), then call the overloaded `()` operator using `find_sum(...)`.

This technique allows you to pass *state* into what essentially is a function.

Answer (score 2):

From `find_sum`, return the so-far maximum sum (instead of `void`). That means that the recursion-terminating code would be:

```
if(index == combine.size())  {
        int sum =0;
        for(int i=0; i<index; ++i)  {
            sum += combine[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

and the recursive part would be

```
int max_sum = 0;
for(int i = start; 
            i < ar.size() && ar.size()-i > combine.size()-index; 
            ++i) {
        combine[index] = ar[i];
        int thismaxsum = find_sum(ar, combine, index+1, start+1);
        if(thismaxssum > max_sum)
            max_sum = thismaxsum;
}
return max_sum;
```

So, the overall solution is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int find_sum(const std::vector<int>& ar, std::vector<int>&  combine,
    int index, int start);


int main() {
    int N = 10;
    int M = 3;
    std::vector<int> ar(N);
    ar = { 0,9,2,3,7,6,1,4,5,8 };

    int index = 0, start = 0;
    std::vector<int> combine(M);
    int max_sum = find_sum(ar, combine, index, start);
    std::cout << max_sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int find_sum(const std::vector<int>& ar, std::vector<int>&  combine,
    int index, int start)
{
    if (index == combine.size())
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<index; ++i)
        {
            sum += combine[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    int max_sum = 0;

    for (int i = start;
        i < ar.size() && ar.size() - i > combine.size() - index;
        ++i)
    {
        combine[index] = ar[i];
        int thismaxsum = find_sum(ar, combine, index + 1, start + 1);
        if (thismaxsum > max_sum)
            max_sum = thismaxsum;
    }

    return max_sum;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested? I think if you have returned, the code is terminated, therefore there won't be compare between `thismaxsum` and `max_sum`.

Comment: int thismaxsum = find_sum(ar, combine, index+1, start+1);**this part**
        if(thismaxssum > max_sum)
            max_sum = thismaxsum;

Comment: The code would not terminate there; `find_sum` returns and the code continues executing the `if`

Comment: Thanks, but why at that point it won't terminate? After all, if you've successfully assigned a value to `thismaxsum`, it means it has already execute the `if` part and has also execute the `return sum` code, the function should terminate then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125154/discussion-between-marek-fekete-and-buzhidao).

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are much better then adding operands and variables to recursion functions because each operand and variable causes heap/stack trashing negatively impact performance and space usage risking stack overflow for higher recursions.

To avoid global variables (for code cosmetics and multi threading/instancing purposes) I usually use context or temp struct. For example like this:

```
// context type
struct f1_context
 {
 // here goes any former global variables and stuff you need
 int n;
 };

// recursive sub function
int f1_recursive(f1_context &ctx)
 {
 if (ctx.n==0) return 0;
 if (ctx.n==1) return 1;
 ctx.n--;
 return (ctx.n+1)*f1_recursive(ctx.n);
 }

// main API function call
int f1(int n)
 {
 // init context
 f1_context ctx;
 ctx.n=n;
 // start recursion
 return f1_recursion(ctx);
 }
```

the `f1(n)` is factorial example. This way the operands are limited to single pointer to structure. Of coarse you can add any recursion tail operands after the context... the context is just for global and persistent stuff (even if I did use it for the recursion tail instead but that is not always possible).